# How to place image next to the text both centered in Foundation 5?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to have image next to the headline in one row, both centered in Foundation 5. Example is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sIjfo).

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel small-12 column">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-5 column text-right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="small-7 column text-left">
        <h1>APP NAME</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example solution isn't ideal because it is not centered exactly especialy on the large screens.

I've also tried something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel small-12 column text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=logo" />
      <h1>APP NAME</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work: image isn't centered. What is the best way how to do this in Foundation 5?

Comment: Use css to style them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `img` is an *inline* element and `h1` is a *block* element, you should put the image inside the heading. [See the JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3ubsuxLy/1/)

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="panel small-12 column text-center">
    <h1><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=logo" alt="" /> APP NAME</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, `alt` is a required attribute, so I've added one with a blank value.